# Problema al ingresar a los valores de mi state : Optional Chaining

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Estoy haciendo una app utilizando una API, mediante un state guardo la informacion del personaje en detalle en la const **character** pero cuando quiero ingresar a la variable **character.origin.name** me da el error de que no puede leer la variable "name"

detail.jsx

```
import { useParams, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { React, useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function Detail() {
  const params = useParams();
  const [character, setCharacter] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/${params.id}`)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((char) => {
        if (char.name) {
          setCharacter(char);
        } else {
          window.alert("No hay personajes con ese ID");
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        window.alert("No hay personajes con ese ID");
      });
    return setCharacter({});
  }, [params.id]);

  return (
    <>
      <header>
        <Link to="/">
          <img
            className="logo"
            src={require("../imagenes/logo.png")}
            alt="logo"
          />
        </Link>
      </header>
      <div>
        <h1>Nombre: {character.name}</h1>
        <img src={character.image} alt={character.image} />
        <h2>Status: {character.status}</h2>
        <h2>Especie: {character.species}</h2>
        <h2>Genero: {character.gender}</h2>
        <h2>Origen: {character.origin.name}</h2>   **<-- este es el problema en cuestion**
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Esto es lo que el state Character esta guardando:

como es que puedo ingresar a la variable que necesito sin que me tire error?

```
{
"id":1,
"name":"Rick Sanchez",
"status":"Alive",
"species":"Human",
"type":"",
"gender":"Male",
"origin":{"name":"Earth (C-137)",
"url":"https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/location/1"},
"location":{"name":"Citadel of Ricks",
"url":"https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/location/3"},
"image":"https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/avatar/1.jpeg"
}
```

Comment: @djrobert, ¿Cual es el mensaje de error que JS arroja?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Muchas veces se tiene problema al acceder a un valor de un objeto, dentro de un objeto, pues si el objeto es undefined, y la propiedad es undefined, estás tratando de obtener el valor de dos undefined en cadena, así que una forma en la que puedes arreglar esto es usando algo llamado **optional chaining**. 
Básicamente es una forma sencilla de acceder a valores de objetos conectados, se usa de esta manera

```js
 <h2>Origen: {character?.origin?.name}</h2>
```

De esta forma, con este operador puedes obtener el valor de name, sólo cuando origin esté definido, y obtener el valor de origin sólo cuando character esté definido. Espero te sirva

Comment: Muchas gracias! me la anoto, apenas estoy entrando a este mundo de java y esto me ayuda mucho:D

Comment: @jorge ¿Que valor regresa si no estan definidos pero se usa optional chaining?

Comment: no regresa valor, te marca error el programa

Comment: ok entonces si hacemos esto `<h2>Origen: {character?.origin?.name}</h2>` pero la propiedad name no viene definida dentro de `character.origin` JS arroja un error por lo cual ¿Ademàs de usar optional chaining hay que validar?

Comment: no leí bien tu pregunta arriba, me corrijo: si no están definidos y usas optional chaining vas a renderizar undefined, pero si no usaras optional chaining te marcaría error, no correría